# Detect wheter a sound buffer is filled with data or not

Tags: c++, audio, voip, voice-recording

I'm recording using WaveAPI, and I want to detect after I'm finish recording the data, if the buffer has sound in it, or it have recorded nothing (just the void of the room).

I wrote a function that gets an average of the absolute value of the buffer, and it works "Ok", but it has many problems :

1) I've detected, that when it is void, the average is ~860, and when I'm talking, it is ~875, which is barely a different at all. How can it be ? I'm recording for 1 sec.

2) Some times, I see that the average is ~860, some times ~500, some days even ~400. Why is it changing every time? I mean, shouldent it be the same, as in all the times it captures the void and there isnt a change ?

Here is the function I wrote :

```
bool isEmpty(short int *wave)
{
int avg = 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < NUMPTS ; i++)
{
    if (wave[i] < 0)
        avg = avg + (wave[i]) * -1;

    else
        avg = avg + (wave[i]);
}

avg = avg / NUMPTS;

if (avg > avg_voice)
    return false;

return true;
}
```

This function isnt good enough, as it isnt allways right, and I have to constatly change the `avg_voice` into something else, and some times the buffer is like only 10 points in the average higher with sound, than with void, which is very hard to detect wheter it has voice in it or not....

So what can I do ? How can I improve it ? Maybe theres an option for that when I record the voice, and fill in all the `WAVEFORMATEX`and `WAVEHDR` settings?

Thanks!

Edit: `wave` is a short int array that contains `8000` cells, and stors the voice inside, and looks like this (example) :
`wave[0] = -123;`
`wave[1] = -205;`
`wave[2] = -212'`

and such...

Second Edit :
I'm recording the data like this :

```
void StartRecord()
{
short int *waveIn = new short int[NUMPTS];

HWAVEIN hWaveIn;
WAVEHDR WaveInHdr;
MMRESULT result;
HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;

WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
pFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
pFormat.nChannels = 1;
pFormat.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;
pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = 2 * sampleRate;
pFormat.nBlockAlign = 2;
pFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
pFormat.cbSize = 0;

result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

if(result)
{
    char fault[256];
    waveInGetErrorTextA(result, fault, 256);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, fault, "Failed to open waveform input device.", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return;
}

WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = 2 * NUMPTS;
WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0;
WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0;
WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0;

while (true)
{
    waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    result = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);
    if(result)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to start recording", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return;
    }

    // Wait until finished recording 
    Sleep(seconds * 1000); //Sleep for as long as there was recorded
    waveInUnprepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    if (isEmpty(waveIn)) // Checks here
                 .....
}
 }
```

Comment: You are more likely to get good responses if the real question is a coding question as opposed to an acoustics question. Your code looks good in general, however (a) How do you derive `avg_voice`?, and (b) Did you try looking into the values collected in `wave[]` (either printing or in debugger)?

Comment: It's hard to see the problem since there is nothing in your posted code that tells how `wave` is initialized.

Comment: @Arun `avg_voice` is a `typedef` I put, and I've simply debuged and seen the buffer average when it is void and when it is with voice, and then put a number manualy in `avg_voice`, and thats why I think my code is bad.

Comment: @RSahu I forgot to mention it. The buffer is an array of 8000 cells of short ints (and thats the buffer - `short int *wave`)

Comment: @Amit How is it initialized before being passed to `isEmpty`?

Comment: @RSahu You mean how do I declare it ? `short int *waveIn = new short int[NUMPTS];`


      , I can also post the code of the recording of the data, and passng it to the function of `isEmpty` if you want...

Comment: @Amit, you can print the data contained in `wave` before passing it to `isEmpty` to make sure that `wave` has the right values.

Comment: @RSahu I know, I've also checked it with the debuger. the problem is, the data that has nothing inside it, is too similar to the data that has voice in it, and therefor, the average isnt allways useful, and I was looking for another method that indicates if the buffer contains voice in it or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I predict that the buffer hasn't been filled by the time you analyze it. Rather than a simple sleep, you should poll for WaveInHdr.dwFlags for the WHDR_DONE bit to be set.

```
result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);
if(result)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to start recording", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return;
}

// Wait until finished recording 
while ((WaveInHdr.dwFlags & WHDR_DONE) == 0)
    Sleep(100);
```

Secondly, I'd suggest a better method of measuring loudness. [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) Perhaps:

```
double Rms(short int *wave, int length)
{
    double sumSquared = 0;
    double scaleShortToDouble = 1.0/0x8000;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < length; i++)
    {
         double s = wave[i] * scaleShortToDouble;
         sumSquared += s * s;
    }
    return sqrt(2) * sqrt(sumSquared/length);
}
```

I've converted the shorts to doubles in the range of -1.0 to 1.0 because its easier to compute with. The extra sqrt(2) is going to scale the result so that if you were to put a sine wave into the A/D converter so that a full scale digital sine comes out (-32768,32767), the Rms result will be 1.0.

With that done, you can now convert the Rms value to dB and you'll have a number that is referred to as [dBFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS) and is commonly used when talking about digital levels.

The conversion is: `dBFS = 20*log10(rms)` and roughly:

- 0 dBFS = 1.0`
- -6 dBFS = 0.5
- -12 dBFS = 0.25

each halving of input level is another -6 dBFS down.

It also happens that each halving of the input signal is going to require one less bit of the A/D converter. Since you have a 16 bit signal, you're theoretical noise floor is going to be at around -96 dBFS. In practice though, since you have a mic hooked up, it's going to be somewhat higher than that - depending in large part upon the quality of your setup. And that's where you're going to need to experiment.

Comment: @Beed. I don't know what I was thinking. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @jaket Thanks! I've googled RMS, yet I did not understand several things :
1) what is `scaleShortToDouble`, and why is it `1.0/0x8000`?
2) I've seen you're changing the short int into double, and then squaring it. then you're using a sqrt on the sum of the squares, divided by the length. What do this mean? as I have near heard of RMS before.
3) how can I use the `double` that `Rms` returns, and see if It is loud enough or not?

Comment: @Amit. 1) `scaleShortToDouble` simply rescales the waveform to the range of -1.0 to 1.0 by multiplying by 1/(2^15). It's often easier to do signal processing in floating point.  2) RMS stands for root mean squared. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square. 3) You need to measure the noise floor of your (considering ambient noise of the room) and set the threshold somewhere a bit higher than that. I'm going to update my answer to include a `* sqrt(2) and explain a little more in there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've noticed that when Im talking, the RMS is usually 0.033 ~ 0.037, so I've set the limite of voice to 0.04, and it is working wonderfull!

Comment: You are building a noise-gate here, and these often have hysteresis - that is to say, dynamic behaviour - operating over more than one sample

Answer (score 1):

**you must use RMS** as sinusoids have an average value of 0 so you will just get the voltage offset of the microphone if you take an average. That's why you are getting inconsistent but low values, 860/2^15 is approximately 2% of the dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated memory for `waveIn` using:

```
short int *waveIn = new short int[NUMPTS];
```

However, that does not initialize the contents. Initialize the contents into something meaningful. Then, you will be able to see where things are not working. If `0` is meaningful default value, use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMPTS; ++i )
{
   waveIn[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when I'm recording into the buffer, all the cells are filled with information, so it does metter if the array is initialize or not. I have added the code of recording the voice...
Also, I think you did not understand my question :

I'm having a full array of short int , at the size of NUMPTS (which is 8000) and the array contains data of the recording from the microphone...

Comment: I need to detect wheter the user has spoke to the microphone, and the buffer actually contains voice inside it, or is it empty buffer (empty buffer isnt nessecery havign 0's, it can look similar to a buffer that contains voice